# How to measure time with Matlab while led diodes is on using Arduino?

Tags: matlab, arduino

I need measure time while led diodes is on for each one with Matlab guide. In Arduino code its sending data to Matlab if diodes are on:

if(digitalRead(ledC1)==HIGH)
   { Serial.println("a"); }

if(digitalRead(ledC2)==HIGH)
   { Serial.println("b"); }

With my Matlab code, it works only if one diode is on, but it is not working if two diodes are on in the same time and not measure for each one. How measure for both diodes?

Matlab code:

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

s=serial('COM7','BaudRate',9600);

fopen(s);

try

```
 while true

   pause(1);
```

A = fscanf(s,'%s');

B = fscanf(s,'%s');

if strcmp(A,'a')==0    % frist led dioda

```
    tic;
```

end

```
    seconds1=toc;
```

elapsedTime1 = fix(mod(seconds1, [0, 3600, 60]) ./ [3600, 60, 1]);

set(handles.text8,'String',elapsedTime1);

if strcmp(B,'b')==0          % second led dioda

```
    tic;
```

end

```
    seconds2=toc;
```

elapsedTime2 = fix(mod(seconds2, [0, 3600, 60]) ./ [3600, 60, 1]);

set(handles.text9,'String',elapsedTime2);

end

end

catch err

fclose(s);

```
clear all


return;
```

end

Comment: Please re-format your Matlab code and elaborate on what you really need.

Comment: Its need to display time in matlab guide while diodes is turn on. Arduino is connected with Matlab and sending data. If first dioda is turn on ,its send string 'a'  to Matlab ,then have to measure time and display.If second dioda is turn on, its send string 'b' then also need to measure and display while dioda is on.

Comment: Instead of commenting about what it should do you must edit your question and include it there.

Comment: Wrong idea ! First measure it later send answer. Your value is fuzzy ! `a = start_time = 0 ; b = end_time = 0 ; if b > a : send_data ; a = b = 0`